# Angular 6: observing properties of nested objects

Tags: angular, model

I've split my data model into subobjects, which roughly correspond to sub- components of the Angular app's main form.

However, to enable/disable buttons in a "cockpit"-like component that is part of the main form, I need to be able to react to changes that can occur on several properties across one or more of the subobjects.

How can I do that efficiently?

[Also, did I make a design mistake when splitting the data into subobjects? I'm new at Angular, this is my first project using it.]

EDIT: as requested, I'll try to paint a more concrete picture (can't post code right now). The top-level data class is `Project`, with a few subojects such as `header`, `quotation`, `items`, etc, each an instance of a corresponding class. (The app is about ordering and billing).

The "cockpit-like" component has buttons for saving, computing prices, creating offers, placing the order, and uploading attachments. These buttons should be disabled according to state, which is scattered across members of the subobjects. I'm looking for a way to make sure that button states (enabled/disabled) are up to date with project state at all times.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code/data model to make this discussion a little more concrete? Also, depending on the scope of your project, a "cockpit" like interface often is well suited to more explicit state management using a library such as NgRx.

Comment: @DeborahK Edited the question to add a bit more detail

Comment: If you went with NgRx, you'd have a single data store for all of your info. If you don't want to go that way, you may want to stick with working with discrete objects and not one monster object. Otherwise you'll end up having to create something that exposes the pieces of it you need. (Similar to what the NgRx selectors do for you.)